# Are sizes of potatoes normally distributed?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, statistics, biostatistics, agriculture

I'm currently researching the **variability of sizes of potatoes** when all of the potatoes in question have been **harvested from a single field**. One question keeps coming up in my statistical analyses: Under normal circumstances, are the sizes of potatoes - within a single field - **normally distributed**? (Please feel free to define the weasel words "normal circumstances" in the most helpful way you can imagine.)

Human height is often given as one of those classic examples of a normally distributed phenomenon. The little that I know about plant biology suggests that the **central limit theorem** applies just as much to potatoes as to the human body: the lengths of potato tubers and the lengths of human bones should have similarly-shaped distributions. But is that correct?

---

*A bit of context to my original question:* what I'm trying to do is to take the mean and standard deviation of my data and then, using the 68-95-99 rule, construct a series of **confidence intervals**, which I can then test or refine by looking at other data sets. Obviously, no real data set is going to conform perfectly to a model; I just need to know that, in principle, potato sizes are normally distributed **enough** that my method for drawing up confidence intervals isn't hopelessly misguided.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding of the central limit theorem (CLT). CLT emphatically does NOT say that all variables in nature are normally distributed. Rather, it says that the sample means are normally distributed (approximately) when sample size is large.

Comment: The only way to find out whether the sizes of potatoes or human beings are normally distributed is empirical measurement.

Comment: @Adhish Forgive me if I didn't express myself as clearly as I might have done. I did not claim that, because of the CLT, all natural phenomena are normally distributed; I merely suggested that, because sizes are normally distributed in humans, it is plausible that they *might* also be normally distributed in potatoes.

Comment: @Adhish 'The only way to find out whether the sizes of potatoes or human beings are normally distributed is empirical measurement.' I was hoping that someone would point me to some empirical research on the topic. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: If you have data from your potatoes of one field, can't you answer empirically what the size distribution is from your own data?

Comment: @BryanKrause I have to emphasise that I'm not a professional statistician, but the data from the one field I've had a chance to examine properly do *seem* to be normally distributed: they're clustered symmetrically around the mean. But it's not a classic bell curve, and I'm anxious about seeing only what I want to see. If someone could point me to a paper that said something like, "Potato sizes generally follow X distribution", that would save me a lot of weeping and gnashing of teeth.

Comment: @Adhish as far as I know, since height is the average of many QTLs it is normally distributed since it becomes a distribution of the means of these genes. I use this alot so I'd like to be corrected on this if I'm wrong

Comment: Most statistical comparisons are comparisons of AVERAGE1 versus AVERAGE2, versus etc. It is the averages that are normally distributed.

Comment: @Hachiloni That seems to be a valid approach, but I'd still say it depends on the trait in question. What is valid for height may not be valid for other quantitative traits. (See https://www.genetics.org/content/204/3/1281 for a discussion on non-normal quantitative traits.) I guess a lot would also depend on how much of a deviation from normality one is willing to tolerate.

Comment: Not an answer, but you might want to reconsider what a normally distributed variable means and why you want to know it, since height seems to deviate significantly https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360254/why-does-the-distribution-of-height-follow-normal-distribution. Also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless

Comment: It is important to keep in mind that the normal distribution is a model. George Box had [something so say about models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong). You should also carefully consider why you care about the distribution of potato size. You might be looking at the wrong thing here (e.g., in regression analysis you'd care about the conditional distribution only) or be able to remove this assumption (non-parametric statistics comes to mind).

Comment: Thank you to everyone for contributing your brain power to this surprisingly tricky question. I've just added some context to my original post which might simplify things a bit.

Comment: If your sample is not too small, you could use bootstrap to derive CIs for the mean, no distribution assumption needed.

Comment: Empirical observation (growing potatos in my garden) suggests not.  From any mature plant (that is, when the tops die back) I will get several large ones about the size you'd find in a store, several smaller ones that might go as "baby" potatos, and a bunch that are marble to pea size.  Presumably commercial growers sort out the small ones before sending the rest to market.

Comment: @TomHosker if you are only trying to calculate CI for the mean of the potato size in the field AND you have enough samples (usually 30) you can assume the mean size of the potato is distributed normally. There are methods to find the best distribution fitting your sample and than you can calculate CI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Evaluation of the Effect of Density on Potato Yield and Tuber Size Distribution](https://acsess.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.2135/cropsci2007.01.0026) potato tuber size was estimated using a normal distribution but **they are not normally distributed**

They found that a Weibull distribution with specific parameters estimated better than a normal distribution.

In fact you should not expect a normal distribution because there are no potatoes of negative size  As such [you expect a gamma distribution.  The Weibull distribution is in the same family of distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77586/weibull-distribution-v-s-gamma-distribution).

But in many cases [the normal distribution is used](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1335872/818846) since the probability of a negative number is negligigble.

Does this mean that potato sizes are still the result of many factors? It would seem so

Comment: The link to "this article" for me yields "access denied".  Perhaps a bit more explicit citation would be good.

Comment: StackExchange answers should stand on their own; other references are great and are even required in many cases here at Biology.SE, but people need to be able to read your answer and understand it by itself, too.

Comment: @BryanKrause could you elaborate? I don't know where to elaborate more. One good article states they are not normally distributed and cites others that say the smae. I edited for the name of the article per mgkrebbs comment

Comment: i added more explanatory text with a reference.

Comment: I'm on the cusp of accepting this answer. I've just added some context - hopefully helpful - to the end of my question. If you could make a brief comment on that, then I'll give you the green tick.

Comment: *As a side note*: I'm not convinced by your claim that 'you should not expect a normal distribution because there are no potatoes of negative size'. There are plenty of normally distributed phenomena which never take negative values. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: If you are looking for the CI of the mean and you sample n >30 you can assume the mean is normally distributed per CLT which is different from the distribution of the potatoes. I added another link explaining why the normal distribution is used for only positive vallues. In short, the probability of a negative is so low that it is ignored